# how to remove matplotlib output lines from showing in jupyter notebook when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

for example, when I plot something and add titles and so forth, I get a list of lines showing output like the ones below before the actual plot shows, sometimes very long lists.

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x244deb8dd68>

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x244deb99358>

<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x244defc9240>
```

Is there a way to hide these when plotting?

Comment: Can you show us how you're adding the titles, etc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add ";" after your matplotlib commands. This seems to suppress output.

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,5))
plt.title('Some Title')
```

Yields:

```
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x119188490>
```

and an image.

Yet:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,5))
plt.title('Some Title');
```

just yields the image.

This was done using python 2 in a v4 Jupyter notebook.